# Help identifying those parts SG7 / EA336L / M71A / 8246 / K333CD?

Tags: identification

Could someone tell me what is those parts are used for?
I tried googling on them but with no results

Attached is the picture on their borad, it's a podometer [image]

Comment: nRF51822 Bluetooth module / communication module / network module / wireless mouse and keyboard module N51822  https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-Smart-Bluetooth-low-energy/nRF51822

Comment: What is a podometer?

Comment: @LeonHeller It counts pods LOL

Comment: The downvoters should tell me why

Comment: My guess is that a simple search engine search pulls the components up.

Comment: No, you are wrong, try it and feedback to me

Comment: @LeonHeller A podometer or pedometer is a device which counts the number of steps you make. If your steps always make the same distance, you can calculate how much distance you walked :-)

Comment: @Leon - A simple google search would have answered what a podometer is. I'm voting to close your comment for lack of prior research ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part labeled K333CD seems to be a low frequency oscillator / quarz. My guess would be it is a watch crystal running at 32.768 kHz.
The component labeled EA336L could be a linear regulator (3.3V output).
The part labeled SG7 is probably a small EEPROM.
That part labeled 8246 seems to be a bit harder to crack. Maybe by knowing what/where that bluetooth-module comes from, or be really reverse engineering the board and check what it actually connects to, you could get an idea where you actually should look.
Of course, this is just logical deduction based on my experience, and you should definately investigate further (by measuring and researching) to confirm my statements.